# Read file to linked list C

Tags: c, file, linked-list

Hello guys i am trying to load file to linked list and then print it to 2 array . i dont know what wrong in my code , i dont know how to sperate for 2 array,when i print it as a string it works but for two array it is not working.i am new in c programming ,
my code:

```
    struct list {
    char *string1;
    struct list *next;
};

    typedef struct list LIST;



 int read_file(char * filename)
int a[20], b[20];
FILE *fp;
char line[128];
LIST *current, *head;
head = current = NULL;
int i = 0;
fopen_s(&fp, filename, "r");
if (fp == NULL) {
    printf("ERROR");
    return 0;
}
while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp)) {
    LIST *node = malloc(sizeof(LIST));
    node->string1 = strdup(line);
    node->next = NULL;
    char str[20];
    char* field = strtok(line, ",");
    strcpy(str, field);
    a[i] = (int)atof(str);
    field = strtok(NULL, ",");
    b[i] = (int)atof(field);
    i++;
    printf("%4d\t%4d\n", a[i],b[i]);
    if (head == NULL) {
        current = head = node;
    }
    else {
        current = current->next = node;


    }
}
fclose(fp);
```

Comment: You have the `i++;` and `printf("%4d\t%4d\n", a[i], b[i]);` lines the wrong way round.

Comment: what ? i didnt understand can u explain me ?